# grouping and summarizing to find mean and median based on Group

Tags: r

I have a data-set comprising of model,Brand and Engine
in the engine column it is having 29 Missing values
I wanted to fill those missing values based on the median or mean of that particular model
How can i do it ?

I have used this syntax:

```
usedcars  %>% 
  group_by(Brand,Model) %>%
  filter(is.na(Engine)) %>%
  summarise(Engine)


Groups:   Brand, Model [210]
   Brand Model     Engine
   <fct> <fct>      <dbl>
 1 Audi  A3-series   1968
 2 Audi  A3-series   1968
 3 Audi  A3-series   1968
 4 Audi  A4          1968
 5 Audi  A4          1968
 6 Audi  A4          1968
 7 Audi  A4          1968
 8 Audi  A4          2967
 9 Audi  A4          1968
10 Audi  A4          1968
```

Comment: the above have been grouped but i am enable to find the mean and median by group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `ifelse`: here example with `mean`. you could use `median` if preferred:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- usedcars %>% 
  group_by(Brand, Model) %>% 
  mutate(Engine_Mean = mean(Engine, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(Engine = ifelse(is.na(Engine), Engine_Mean, Engine), .keep="unused")
```

Output:

```
   Brand Model     Engine
   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
 1 Audi  A3-series  1968 
 2 Audi  A3-series  1968 
 3 Audi  A3-series  1968 
 4 Audi  A4         1968 
 5 Audi  A4         1968 
 6 Audi  A4         1968 
 7 Audi  A4         1968 
 8 Audi  A4         2967 
 9 Audi  A4         1968 
10 Audi  A4         2093.
11 Audi  A3-series  1968 
12 Audi  A3-series  1968 
13 Audi  A3-series  1968 
14 Audi  A4         2093.
15 Audi  A4         2093.
16 Audi  A4         2093.
17 Audi  A4         2093.
18 Audi  A4         2093.
19 Audi  A4         1968 
20 Audi  A4         1968
```

Example data:

```
usedcars <- tribble(
~Brand, ~Model,     ~Engine,
"Audi",  "A3-series",   1968,
"Audi",  "A3-series",   1968,
"Audi",  "A3-series",   1968,
"Audi",  "A4",          1968,
"Audi",  "A4",          1968,
"Audi",  "A4",          1968,
"Audi",  "A4",          1968,
"Audi",  "A4",          2967,
"Audi",  "A4",          1968,
"Audi",  "A4",          NA,
"Audi",  "A3-series",   NA,
"Audi",  "A3-series",   NA,
"Audi",  "A3-series",   NA,
"Audi",  "A4",          NA,
"Audi",  "A4",          NA,
"Audi",  "A4",          NA,
"Audi",  "A4",          NA,
"Audi",  "A4",          NA,
"Audi",  "A4",          1968,
"Audi",  "A4",          1968)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)

usedcars%>%
  group_by(Brand,Model)%>%
         #replace NA with mean
  mutate(Engine_mean = replace(Engine, is.na(Engine), mean(Engine, na.rm = TRUE)), 
         #Replace NA with median
         Engine_median = replace(Engine, is.na(Engine), median(Engine, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use `na.aggregate` from `zoo` (by default, it replaces the missing values with `mean`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
usedcars <- usedcars %>%
       group_by(Brand, Model) %>%
       mutate(Engine_mean = na.aggregate(Engine),
              Engine_median = na.aggregate(Engine, FUN = median))
```